Input variable into Label List causing error with string
This script works with the Label section hardcoded:
import oci
import pandas as pd

# Create a default config using DEFAULT profile in default location
config = oci.config.from_file()

# Initialize service client with default config file
data_labeling_service_dataplane_client = oci.data_labeling_service_dataplane.DataLabelingClient(config)

# Define the Excel file location
excel_file_path = r'C:\SMALLFILEEXCEL.xlsx'

# Load the Excel file into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, header=None)  # No header row

# Loop through each row in the DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Ensure there are two columns (record_id and labels)
    if len(row) < 1:
        print(f"Skipping row due to insufficient data: {row}")
        continue

    # Get the record_id and strip any unwanted characters (spaces, newlines)
    record_id2 = row[0].strip()

    label_str = row[1].strip()

    # Print the cleaned record_id for debugging purposes
    print(f"Using record_id: {record_id2}")

    try:
        # Create annotation request for each record
        create_annotation_response = data_labeling_service_dataplane_client.create_annotation(
            create_annotation_details=oci.data_labeling_service_dataplane.models.CreateAnnotationDetails(
                record_id=record_id2,  # Use the cleaned record_id without quotes
                compartment_id="myid",  # Replace with your compartment_id
                entities=[
                    oci.data_labeling_service_dataplane.models.GenericEntity(
                        entity_type="GENERIC",
                        labels=[oci.data_labeling_service_dataplane.models.Label(label="macular_edema"),
                                oci.data_labeling_service_dataplane.models.Label(label="scar")]
                    )
                ],
                freeform_tags={'example_key_2': 'example_value_2'},
                defined_tags={'example_key_3': {'example_nested_key': 'example_nested_value'}}
            ),
            opc_retry_token="a12354123",
            opc_request_id="example_opc_request_id"
        )

        # Print the response for each annotation created
        print(create_annotation_response.data)

    except oci.exceptions.ServiceError as e:
        # Print the full error details for debugging
        print(f"ServiceError: {e.message}")
        print(f"Request ID: {e.request_id}")
        print(f"Status Code: {e.status}")
        print(f"Error Code: {e.code}")
        print(f"Using record_id: {record_id2}")


But when trying to update the Labels with the value from my Excel file like this:
type heimport oci
import pandas as pd

# Create a default config using DEFAULT profile in default location
config = oci.config.from_file()

# Initialize service client with default config file
data_labeling_service_dataplane_client = oci.data_labeling_service_dataplane.DataLabelingClient(config)

# Define the Excel file location
excel_file_path = r'C:\SMALLFILEEXCEL.xlsx'

# Load the Excel file into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, header=None)  # No header row

# Loop through each row in the DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Ensure there are two columns (record_id and labels)
    if len(row) < 1:
        print(f"Skipping row due to insufficient data: {row}")
        continue

    # Get the record_id and strip any unwanted characters (spaces, newlines)
    record_id2 = row[0].strip()

    label_str = row[1].strip()

    # Print the cleaned record_id for debugging purposes
    print(f"Using record_id: {record_id2}")

    try:
        # Create annotation request for each record
        create_annotation_response = data_labeling_service_dataplane_client.create_annotation(
            create_annotation_details=oci.data_labeling_service_dataplane.models.CreateAnnotationDetails(
                record_id=record_id2,  # Use the cleaned record_id without quotes
                compartment_id="compartmentid",  # Replace with your compartment_id
                entities=[
                    oci.data_labeling_service_dataplane.models.GenericEntity(
                        entity_type="GENERIC",
                        labels=label_str
                    )
                ],
                freeform_tags={'example_key_2': 'example_value_2'},
                defined_tags={'example_key_3': {'example_nested_key': 'example_nested_value'}}
            ),
            opc_retry_token="a12354123",
            opc_request_id="example_opc_request_id"
        )

        # Print the response for each annotation created
        print(create_annotation_response.data)

    except oci.exceptions.ServiceError as e:
        # Print the full error details for debugging
        print(f"ServiceError: {e.message}")
        print(f"Request ID: {e.request_id}")
        print(f"Status Code: {e.status}")
        print(f"Error Code: {e.code}")
        print(f"Using record_id: {record_id2}")
re

I get the error:
raise TypeError('Field {} with value {} was expected to be of type {} but was of type {}'.format(field_name, str(obj), declared_type, type(obj).__name__))

TypeError: Field entities[*].labels with value oci.data_labeling_service_dataplane.models.Label(label="scar"), oci.data_labeling_service_dataplane.models.Label(label="nevus"), oci.data_labeling_service_dataplane.models.Label(label="increased_cup_disc")
was expected to be of type list[Label] but was of type str
Any idea how to get that list[Label] to work with a value from the Excel file? My Excel file has that entire text in one cell that it is pulling over. I can update the Excel file if needed.
I tried creating a list without using strings at all which did not work.

It's unclear where this raise statement is in your code, and it's obfuscating the actual error you presumably get. It would be better to just share the stacktrace for the error you originally got. I'll note that labels=label_str seems to assign a single string to labels, while labels=oci.data_labeling_service_dataplane.models.Label(label="macular_edema"),                                 oci.data_labeling_service_dataplane.models.Label(label="scar")] appears to assign a list of strings - that's probably a good place to start looking.
